How to evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{x} \ln^2(1 - x) \, dx$

Question

How to evaluate $$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{x} \ln^2(1 - x) \, dx$$

My attempt

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{x} \ln^2(1 - x) \, dx &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1 - x)}{1 + x^2 y^2} \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \ln^2(1 - x) \cdot \frac{i}{1 + x^2 y^2} \, dx \, dy \\
&= \Im \left( \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(x) \cdot (y - yx - 1)}{dx} \, dy \right) \\
&= \Im \left( \int_0^1 \frac{1}{y} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(x)}{1 - \frac{i}{y} - x} \, dx \, dy \right) \\
&= \Im \left( \int_0^1 \frac{1}{y} \left[ -\ln^2(x) \ln\left(1 - \frac{i}{y} - x\right) \bigg|_0^1 + 2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x) \ln\left(1 - \frac{i}{y} - x\right)}{x} \, dx \right] \, dy \right) \\
&= \Im \left( \int_0^1 \frac{1}{y} \left[ -\ln\left(1 - \frac{i}{y}\right) \zeta^2(1) - 
\int_0^1 \left[ \frac{1}{x} \left( \log\left(1 - \frac{i}{y} \ln(x)\right) - \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{1 - \frac{i}{y}}\right) \right) \right] \, dx \, dy \right] \right) \\
&= \Im \left( \int_0^1 \frac{2}{y} \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{i}{y}}\right) \, dy \right)
\end{align}
Now i am completely stuck

The second line of your attempt suddenly has an $i$ in it? The next line somehow moves $dx$ into the denominator?

The integral $I=\int_0^1 \frac{ \ln^2(1 - x) \tan^{-1}x }{x}, dx$ is super-duper involved, which should not be tried leisurely
$$I= 2\Im Li_4(\frac1{1+i})+\ln2 \ \Im Li_3(\frac1{1+i})+\frac{35\pi}{128}\zeta(3)-(\frac{5\pi^2}{48}-\frac14\ln^2 2 )G-\frac\pi{48}\ln^32
$$

@Quanto What is $G$? Is it the Euler-Mascheroni constant? What is $Li_n()$? I assume it's some variation of logarithmic integral, but I'm not sure what the subscript signifies.

@PM2Ring G is the Catalan constant and $Li_n$ are polylogrithmic functions

@Quanto Like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm

Maybe you can use the fact that $\arctan x = \Im \log(1+ix)$ and then consider the integral
$$\int\frac{[\log(1+ix) -\log(1-x)]^3}x$$

Why downvote???

I have no idea why your question got downvotes, but maybe you should address the points raised by Thomas Andrews.

I didn’t understand why they asked. I just used simple identities and converted arctan(x) into a logarithm. Well, I’m used to it—my questions often get downvoted and closed without any reason.

We need the classical result,
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}\log^2(1-x)\textrm{d}x=\frac{2}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{H_{k}}{k}=\frac{H_{n}^2+H_n^{(2)}}{n}, \tag1$$
also given in (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019), page $2$.
Using the power series of arctan, which we combine with $(1)$, we get the following integral transformation into series,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_{2 n-1}^2}{(2 n-1)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_{2 n-1}^{(2)}}{(2 n-1)^2}.$$
The remaining sums can be immediately extracted by using their corresponding generating functions,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n \frac{H_n^2}{n^2}$$
$$=2\zeta(4)-\frac{1}{3}\log(x)\log^3(1-x)-\log^2(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\frac{1}{2}(\operatorname{Li}_2(x))^2$$
$$+2\log(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\operatorname{Li}_4(x)-2\operatorname{Li}_4(1-x), \ |x|\le1 \land  \ x\neq 0,1,$$
and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n \frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}$$
$$=-2\zeta(4)-2\zeta(3)\log(1-x)-\zeta(2)\log^2(1-x)-\frac{1}{12}\log^4(1-x)$$
$$+\frac{1}{3}\log(x)\log^3(1-x)+\frac{1}{2}(\operatorname{Li}_2(x))^2+2\log(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_4(x)$$
$$
+2\operatorname{Li}_4(1-x)-2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right), \ |x|\le1 \land  \ x\neq 0,1,$$
which are both given in More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series: A New Collection of Fiendish Problems and Surprising Solutions (2023), pages $401-402$, which is the sequel of (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019).
Plug in $x=i$ and take the imaginary parts. The rest is boring, trivial work.
End of Story
A note: I understand that one also needs to simplify everything when it comes to the polylogarithms with a complex argument. Check pages $770-779$ in the sequel, and done.

Nice and simple (+1)

@AliShadhar It's anything but simple;)

Incomplete solution
Consider the parametrized integral with the expansion of $\frac{arctan x}{x}$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(a) & =\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x)^a \arctan x}{x} d x \\
& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2 n+1} \int_0^1(1-x)^a x^{2 n} d x\\&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2 n+1} B(a+1,2n+1)
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\quad  \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x}{x} \ln ^2(1-x) d x \\&=I^{\prime \prime}(0) \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2 n+1}\frac{d^2}{da^2}  B(a+1,2n+1)\Big|_{a=0}\\&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(2 n)!}{2 n+1} \frac{(\psi(2 n+2))^2+2 \gamma \psi(2 n+2)-\psi^{\prime}(2 n+2)+\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\gamma^2}{(2 n+1)!}\\& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)^2}(\psi(2 n+2))^2+2 \gamma \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)^2} \psi(2 n+2)\\& \quad   -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)^2} \psi^{\prime}(2 n+2)+\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\gamma^2\right) G
\end{aligned}
$$
I am stuck in the last three summations and seeking for help!

Good idea ! The problem is I do not see how to exploit the fact that $$I(a)=\frac{1}{a+1},,,
_4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{a+2}{2},\frac{a+3}{2};-1\right)$$

It is quite hard to differentiate $_4F_3 $ twice, isn’t it?

It is not hard but awful ! Cheers :-)

Nice approach (+1). About your sums, try to reindex and convert polygamma to harmonic number.

Thank you for your good idea.  I”ll try later.

If you use
$$\log ^2(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{b_n}\,x^{n+2}$$ where the $a_n$ and $b_n$ correspond respectively to sequences $A002547$ and $A002548$ in $OEIS$ (all of them are positive).
If
$$c_n=\frac {a_n}{b_n}\quad \implies \quad 
c_n=\frac {(n-1) (2 n-3)\,c_{n-1}-(n-2)^2 \,c_{n-2}} {n(n-1) }$$ with $c_0=c_1=0$ and $c_2=1$.
$$\int_0^1\frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x}\,\log ^2(1-x)\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\,\int_0^1x^{n+1}\tan ^{-1}(x)\,dx$$
$$I_n=\int_0^1x^{n+1}\tan ^{-1}(x)\,dx=\frac 1{4(n+2)}\  \left(H_{\frac{n-1}{4}}-H_{\frac{n+1}{4}}+\pi \right)$$
Notice  that
$$\frac {I_{n+1}}{I_n}=1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2+3 \pi }{\pi n^2}
+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ and that
$$\frac {c_{n+1}}{c_n}=1-\frac{3}{4 n}+\frac{2}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ make
$$\frac {c_{n+1}\,I_{n+1}}{c_n\,I_n}=1-\frac{7}{4 n}+\frac{8+23 \pi }{4 \pi  n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
This explains why the convergence is extremely slow.
Edit
Using @pisoir's solution, we should have
$$I=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}C+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}\Big( \left(H_{2 n+1}\right){}^2-\psi^{(1)}(2 n+2) \Big)$$
If $a_n$ is the summand, asymptotically
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|\sim 1-\frac{2 (\log (2 n)+\gamma -1)}{n(\log (2 n)+\gamma )}$$
Writing
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=0}^5 a_n+\sum_{n=6}^\infty a_n$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^5 a_n=\frac{1849621400198491}{115319551000500
   0}-\frac{5478212 \pi ^2}{36018675}$$ and using for the second sum the series expansion of $a_n$ to $O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$, converted to decimals
$$\sum_{n=6}^\infty a_n=0.03281866808520456317573078\cdots$$ This gives
$I=\color{red}{1.64232}71$.

Here is an option, however, not a closed-form solution. Expand $\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}$ into a series, i.e.,
$$\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1}.$$
Thus, you need to evaluate:
$$\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n}\ln^2(1-x)dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\int_0^1(x^n\ln(1-x))^2dx.$$
According to WA, the integral has a (very ugly) "closed form" solution involving hypergeometric functions (WA), which evaluating for each $n$ leads to a sum:
$$=2-\frac{1}{3}\frac{85}{54}+\frac{1}{5}\frac{12019}{9000}-\frac{1}{7}\frac{726301}{617400}+...\approx1.64233$$

@PM2Ring  $x^{2n}\ln^2(1-x)=(x^n\ln(1-x))^2$.

Series sum calculated in Sage, accelerated using Wynn's Epsilon method. 1.6423281588905113752095414967489802803894

https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtkUFr4zAQhe%5F6FQ8WVpKrpFahXQhoj7ntHnJNE5DxOAgsWZbsTUjpfy%2D2li2FvUhi3sybb0aNmzIM9EvNDnsYHMj2e0d9Kxo3ZckoLvJhv6WYXT8EIVlMLkyi429F221f6J1Lxv7YJLjnCu3grQuGuzDRhRKXzOY8exL%2Dp6kluwsvYbCqyfZC3M4eFfrhIvTmJuX5SeGmUCtoydg3%5FJ59QwlDh4mSz1v8mvOEhjC0LQuzh8HzD1YwRS1ZphEGxxPrhgQHF5CTDRcSYfZyxwDgWpLFRsuzwyPEU%2DXwAC1R4S6clGtWxoPBtTxp3NoYKbQiF7FswSlcFbIC5wqZouGvYdlF%5FAtRn1AhzP6TpaBohU%2DaTKOGWa6j3p2Ke6ZxMRxLXCsc4wK4sCZsMEosjlFhVEiL791F8a9qPbQsXq6D%2D65Lqy%5FkHX%5Fz9ia8jcI2ea2Rcv3OdYgll%5FpM%5F6ms1h5fZ%5F4A7Dig2w==&lang=sage

A physicist's approach.
To avoid analytical difficulties, we use the following approximation:
$$\arctan x \approx \frac{\pi}{56}x\left ( 19-5x \right )$$
$$0\leqslant x\leqslant 1$$
Then
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{x} \ln^2(1 - x) \, dx$$
and
$$I\approx \frac{\pi}{56}\int_0^1\left ( 19-5x \right ) \ln^2(1 - x) \, dx=\frac{117}{224}\pi$$
The absolute deviation from the exact value is $0.00141$
